# Insert into a table from other table with condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables which is table country and company. I want to copy the country_id from table country to column country_id from table company.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMcuv.png)

This my current mysql query:

INSERT INTO company (country_id) SELECT a.country_id FROM country a, company b WHERE a.country_name = b.country_name

But it not working. The result is it create new row instead of fill in the company row

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want to do an update, not an insert.

```
UPDATE company AS cmp
LEFT JOIN country AS cnt 
ON cmp.country_name=cnt.country_name
SET cmp.country_id=cnt.country_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to actually do an *update* here:

```
UPDATE company a
INNER JOIN country b
    ON a.country_name = b.country_name
SET country_id = b.country_id;
```